# Why does a simpler model performs better than a complicated one?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, machine-learning-model, model-selection

This has happened to me, a complicated model couldn't solve the problem when a simpler one solved it in a few epochs. How is that? I believed that a more complicated model means more number of parameters and more number of parameters means a higher capability to solve a problem.

I have heard that people say, **A simpler Model can perform well because it has a low variance**. But, what does that even mean?

Comment: What do you call "a simpler model" ? A model using less variables ? A model easier to implement ? With less parameters ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

High variance means that your model's performance varies from data to data, which is bad for the model.

***For example:***
You used a polynomial classifier with high degree, so it will overfit your training data resulting in good accuracy, but when tried on a different dataset it will yield less accuracy , resulting in variance.

[image: This will help you understand]

- The image on the right is way too complex which results in overfitting.
- The middle image shows a simpler model than the image on right, but fits the data better ie. generalize the data better